# REQUEST: Modern day European dial tones and internal rings

Tags: sound-effects-recording, futz

Hi all,

Anyone able to do a quickie record of a London phone dial tone and internal ringing? Appreciate it, thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Michael I have created my own [UK telephone tones](https://soundcloud.com/awfulnicesound/sets/uk-telephone-tones)!

I'll still take recordings that anyone would like to send, of course.

Comment: @Jay those sound fairly accurate.  Can probably do some recordings later in the week if no one else can do before.

Comment: @Bit Depth, I would appreciate that.

Comment: @Jay I can do these recordings tomorrow if you still need them?  Did you want them from the phone earpiece or from a larger speaker?

Comment: @Bit Depth, both perspectives would be great to have. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jay I did a couple of recording for you today. I don't actually have a phone in the studio so these were done in my office.  These were recorded from the phones (shown in pic) inbuilt speaker as the recordings directly form the earpiece were very poor due background office noise.  Anyway, hopefully they will be what you are after, if not just let me know.  You can access the recordings from: https://soundcloud.com/bit_depth/sets/uk-telephone 

Comment: @Jay Forgot to say that these recordings are "as is", other than top-n-tailing I have not done anything to them. 

Comment: @Bit Depth, thank you for doing that! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Jay,
even though I don't live in the UK and can't help you with an actual recording, maybe this will help you in case you can't get a recording:
http://blog.trumpton.org.uk/2010/10/uk-dial-and-progress-tones.html

Hope it helps you

Comment: @Michael Manzke, wow! What a crazy page! Thanks for that -

Comment: glad it helps....even though I'm not sure if the UK tone is 350Hz+450Hz or 350Hz+440Hz.Some pages say 450,some say 440 :(